# `New` folder name giving parse/syntax error at `namespace` line

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

- Laravel Version: 5.5.
- PHP Version: 7.0.0

> exception: "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError"

> file: "/app/Http/Controllers/New/Folder/FlightController.php"

> line: 3

> message: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'New' (T_NEW), expecting identifier (T_STRING)"

Getting parse/syntax error for using `New` as the Folder name

`app/Http/Controllers/New/Folder/FlightController.php`

```
<?php

namespace app\Http\Controllers\New\Folder; // This is error line as per complete Error message

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Flight;

class FlightController extends Controller
{
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not the new in `app\Http\Controllers\New`, should this also match the directory `app/Http/Controllers/NewFolder/`?

Comment: `Flight::where('email', $request->email)` shouldn't ever return `null`. What exactly are you trying to achieve with that line? I only ask because I'm pretty sure there is a better way to achieve it.

Comment: @NigelRen It was a typo it is `app\Http\Controllers\New`.

Comment: You can achieve what you're after with `Flight::updateOrCreate(['email' => $request->email], ['name' => $request->name]);`

Comment: @Rwd for response I'll give it a try.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#other-creation-methods

Comment: @Rwd If I want to `updateOrCreate` multiple attribute.         ```$flight = App\Models\Flight::updateOrCreate(['email' => $request->email], [
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'mobile_no' => $request->mobile_no            
        ]);```

Comment: Which line is he syntax error on?

Comment: Namespace `namespace App\Model;` should be `namespace App\Models;`. In Flight.php

Comment: The first array of `updateOrCreate` contains the attributes to search for, the second array is for the attributes that will be updated. If the model doesn't already exist then the two arrays will be merged together so you don't need to include the `email` in the second array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't use [reserved words](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.php) for variable/file/directory name**. Programming 101.

Beside that [you can have `New` as directory name if PHP8 is being used](https://3v4l.org/9ZNQY).

Answer (score 1):

```
    $tObject = new Flight;
    $flight = Flight::where('email', $request->email) ?? $tObject;
```

Comment: `$tObject = new Flight;` also giving me the same parse/syntax error.

Comment: do you have any function named new? if you does change it to different name?

Comment: No there is no function named `new`

Comment: No, There is no function named `new` but there is folder named `New`

Comment: myabe just don't use new as your folder name as well

Comment: also your namespace should stop at your folder name, unless your FlightController.php in under FloghtController folder
namespace app\Http\Controllers\New\Folder;